# "Здравствуйте, Анна" или "Здравствуйте Анна"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в деловом письме?

Comment: Вы знаете, просто на одном сайте возник спор:
Обращение выделяется запятыми, но в выражении: "Здравствуйте Вася", имя и является частью обращения.
Если мы обращаемся:"Здравствуйте Вася, хотелось бы уточнить...итп", то мы обращаемся к Васе, а уже потом излагаем суть.
А вот ежели:"Здравствуйте, Вася не подскажете...", то мы просто здороваемся, а уже потом просим у Васи чего-то.
В сочетании:"Здравствуйте Вася.", запятая не нужна, потому что мы просто поздоровались с Васей, и предложение закончено. Запятая должна ставиться тогда, когда мы продолжаем предложение дальше, и просим Васю о чём-то.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Всем.
Спасибо большое за ответ! Теперь я с полной уверенностью буду ставить запятую после слова "Здравствуйте"

Comment: Ксиаим, "здравствуйте, всем" - очень неудачная форма, ибо обращение должно стоять в именительном падеже (не "всем", а "все")

Comment: "Здравствуйте - кому" это не просто ошибка. Это вполне себе по-одесски. И не только.  
Некоторое оправдание даже с точки зрения нормативности: это сокращение от *говорю всем "Здравствуйте!"*  
~~~  
Виктор, ну почему вас так тянет на реальные имена на форуме? 
Я понимаю, когда оно из ника следет, но если человек специально прячется за ником?!

Comment: Простите, что сама же и увожу вопрос немного в другое русло, но ваши дискуссии навеяли ещё один вопрос: обычно в теме письма мы пишем: "Вниманию Васи (кому)", а почему нельзя написать "Внимание Васи (кого)" ?

Comment: "Вниманию Васи" - по сути "Предлагается вниманию Васи...[нечто]". Если же "Внимание, Вася!" - нужна запятая. Это просто призыв к вниманию.

Answer (score 8):

Если Здравствуйте - это фамилия Васи или Ани, то запятая не нужна, во всех остальных случаях запятая обязательна.

Comment: Фамилию Васи просклоняем?

Answer (score 7):

Столько ответов, а поставили целых три минуса. Коль столько ответов, значит вопрос хороший. Ставлю плюс.

Полностью согласна с behemothus. Действительно, все недоразумения со знаками объясняются смешением значения слова "обращение" в обычном значении (речь- обращение к кому-либо: например, обращение президента к народу) и в грамматическом. С точки зрения грамматики, обращение - это слово или словосочетание, называющее того, к кому обращаются. Обращение обязательно выделяется  запятыми (или одной запятой, если это начало или конец предложения. Обращение также может отделяться от последующего предложения восклицательным знаком. Не являются обращениями личные местоимения.

Comment: >Столько ответов, а поставили целых три минуса. Коль столько ответов, значит вопрос хороший. Ставлю плюс.   

Да, вот тут уже я согласен.

Comment: А как насчет такой фразы: "Эй, ты! Подойди сюда!" ?

Comment: Ну конечно, поставьте запятую. Но фраза разговорная, грубая, а правила у нас все больше к книжной литературной речи относятся. Часто в предложении типа "Маша, ты сделала уроки?"   ставят запятую и после ты, считая это обращением.  Виктор, Вы же это знаете!Тоже начинаете провоцировать? Если бы не подпись, подумала бы, что комментарий не Ваш.

Comment: Ларf, насколько понимаю, вопрос связан не с разговорностью фразы, а с утверждением  "Не являются обращениями личные местоимения". Это не совсем так. Безусловно они не являются обращениями так, где они являются подлежащим (как, впрочем, и другими чтенами предложения). Но в реким случаях, в повелительном наклонении, например, местоимения второго лица оказываются в роли обращения. Грубость и разговорность - тоже не обязательное свойство такой фразы:  
"Подойдите, вы оба, подойдите к кассе".

Comment: Спасибо, Андрей, что поддержали!

Comment: А разве ВЫ ОБА не пример разговорного стиля

Comment: Лорана, но ведь разговорный стиль - это разновидность стиля литературного языка

Comment: >А разве ВЫ ОБА не пример..  
   
Разве? Мы сейчас опять свалимся на обсуждение то, что такое разговорный стиль (а вопрос, как я понял, совсем не однозначен), но в данном случае не вижу причин отказываться от примера. Ну пусть в конце концов будет без "оба".

>Спасибо, Андрей, что поддержали!    
  
О чем Вы?   
~~~
Виктор, ну что вас так и тянет на реальные имена на форуме? Я понимаю, когда человек себе такой ник заделывает, но если он специально за ником прячется?!  
У меня перед глазами как после этого панибратства хороший форум мгновенно превратился в междусобойчик на коммунальной кухне.

Answer (score 4):

Нужна обязательно во всех случаях, даже в личном письме, если есть желание писать грамотно. Обращение "Анна" должно быть обособлено запятой.

Answer (score 4):

Такие вещи регулярно всплывают на разных сайтах. 
Надо сказать, что аргументы против запятой бывают самыми разнообразными, иногда не лишенными доли здравого смысла. Но как правило все доводы разбиваются об элементарное соображение. И правила пунктуации, и отнесение к *обращению* той или иной части фразы (последнее - специально для ваших собеседников) определяется не смыслом фразы, а чисто грамматическими, достаточно формальными категориями. Обращение - это то, что называет конкретного человека (объект) или группу, выделяя его или её среди прочих подобных. Всё остальное - пожелания, слова вежливости, комплименты и прочая, и прочая, и прочая - грамматически к обращению не относится. Запятые нужны здесь не потому, что их надо всегда ставить после "здравствуйте" (хотя это *почти* всегда так), а потому только, что они нужны перед Васями и Анями. И после Васей и Аней, кстати, тоже. Разумеется, если это не конец или начало предложения.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, запятая нужна. Это правило никто не отменял.

Answer (score 1):

В данном контексте *здравствуйте* - не глагол, а этикетное междометие, отглагольного типа (от *здравствовать*), в предложении является подлежащим. Лингвисты ведут споры по поводу отнесения этикетных формул к какой-либо части речи, но мы не будем принимать это за основу и рассмотрим данную группу слов как междометия, ведь смысл слова *здравствуйте* очень косвенно соотносится с пожеланием здоровья собеседнику; зачастую это просто форма "социальных поглаживаний".

Как правило, если этикетное междометие стоит в одном предложении с обращением, как то "*Здравствуйте, Вася*", запятая обязательна, причем обособляется не само междометие, а обращение. Обособление можно элементарно проверить интонационно. Главное, не путайте случаи, когда обращение и "соседнее" слово образуют единую синтаксическую единицу: *уважаемый Вася*, если актуален вопрос деловой речи.

В общем, обращения - всегда обособляются, если не входят в единую синтаксическую структуру с этикетным междометием.

Само же слово *здравствуйте* может и не обособляться, если это слово употребляется в архаичной его форме, то есть как глагол: "Здравствуете или хандрите, Вася?" При этом, как ни крути, обращение - обособить.

Comment: *В данном контексте здравствуйте - не глагол, а этикетное междометие, отглагольного типа (от здравствовать), в предложении является подлежащим* - хотелось бы источник этого откровения. Чудинова со товарищи не предлагать.

Comment: А вообще *междометие в роли подлежащего* - это сильно. А "Вася" в какой роли тогда? Что-то больно Митрофанушку напоминает с дверью "в роли" прилагательного.

Answer (score 0):

В любом случае обращение "Анна" отделяется запятой от глагола

Answer (score -1):

Всю жизнь помню школьное обучение: "Здравствуйте Анна!", но "Анна, здравствуйте!", т.е. в приветствии не ставится запятая, а в обращении ставится.

Comment: Значит, вы плохо помните школьное обучение всю жизнь. Обращение всегда выделяется запятыми. (А *здравствуйте, Анна!* обращение.)

Comment: В приветствии содержится обращение. Приветствуя Анну, к ней же и обращаются. Это материал 5 класса.